# Rails where query from previous query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have two models Stores and its associated Location. These are the results from a sort query that I'm performing on the Locations.

```
 locations
=>
[#<Location:0x00007f11e46f3fe0
  id: 1,
  street: "Av. Cabildo 2569, CABA",
  store_id: 1,
  created_at: Fri, 24 Feb 2023 15:45:54.010367000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 24 Feb 2023 15:45:54.010367000 UTC +00:00,
  latitude: -34.5575623,
  longitude: -58.4603057>,
 #<Location:0x00007f11e46f3f40
  id: 12,
  street: "Av. Cabildo 1721, CABA",
  store_id: 12,
  created_at: Fri, 24 Feb 2023 15:46:05.441025000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 24 Feb 2023 15:46:05.441025000 UTC +00:00,
  latitude: -34.5653145,
  longitude: -58.4533561>,
 #<Location:0x00007f11e46f3ea0
  id: 2,
  street: "Av. del Libertador 7112, CABA",
  store_id: 2,
  created_at: Fri, 24 Feb 2023 15:45:55.195210000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 24 Feb 2023 15:45:55.195210000 UTC +00:00,
  latitude: -34.5473559877551,
  longitude: -58.456853732653066>,
 #<Location:0x00007f11e46f3e00
  id: 5,
  street: "Av. Monroe 3548, CABA",
  store_id: 5,
  created_at: Fri, 24 Feb 2023 15:45:58.467227000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 24 Feb 2023 15:45:58.467227000 UTC +00:00,
  latitude: -34.565225305050504,
  longitude: -58.47077223030303>,
 #<Location:0x00007f11e46f3d60
  id: 9,
  street: "Av. Alvarez Thomas 1502, CABA",
  store_id: 9,
  created_at: Fri, 24 Feb 2023 15:46:02.374639000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 24 Feb 2023 15:46:02.374639000 UTC +00:00,
  latitude: -34.578532,
  longitude: -58.4633422>,
 #<Location:0x00007f11e46f3720
  id: 7,
  street: "Av. Entre Rios 415, CABA",
  store_id: 7,
  created_at: Fri, 24 Feb 2023 15:46:00.526888000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 24 Feb 2023 15:46:00.526888000 UTC +00:00,
  latitude: -34.614050628571434,
  longitude: -58.39184948571429>]
```

What I want now is to make a query to Stores using this information and retrieve only these Stores, using the associated store_id to point at the Store.id which I think should be something like

`stores = Store.where(id: location.store_id)`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you specifically not want to join the tables, e.g., deliberately do a new query for each location's store(s)?

Comment: This is almost guarenteed to be an [X Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You most likely should not have loaded the records and instead used a join or a subquery to get the right data. Rewind a little bit and tell us what the original problem you were trying to solve was, what your models and schema look like and what the desired result is.

Comment: Is `locations` really an `Array` or is it an `ActiveRecord::Relation`?